# how do i explain sinusoidal functions to a teenager?

Tags: functions, trigonometry

Recently my little sister began studying sinusoidal functions at school. I was trying to explain to her that there is a relationship between these functions and circles, But then she asked " why are they making me use these on triangles if they have to do with circles?" and i was kind of lost.

Does anybody have a good take on giving a good elementary explanation on how these relate to circles and why we use them on triangles in school??

Thank you very much for your help!!

Comment: Wouldn't it be better for her teacher to explain it?

Comment: i mean the point of asking the question here is so i can help her at home.

Comment: Often sine, cosine, and tangent are introduced using "soh cah toa", and without mentioning circles. Personally I'd make sure she understands that first before bringing circles into the picture.

Comment: Perfectly reasonable question.

Answer (score 5):

This is how the triangle relates to the circle in the definition of sine and cosine.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

When you choose a point on a unit circle drawn on a xy-plane, the x projection is a cosine and the y projection is a sine. Projections and the radius-vector form right triangle with hypotenuse being equal to 1 and legs equal to sine and cosine.